# Creating custom regions with Google Geochart

Tags: google-visualization

I want to highlight a number of different regions (e.g. all countys) of a country map. Is this possible to achieve when using Google Charts, not using the default bubble-shaped markers? I want the highlights to look like regular drawn regions (i.e. custom regions).

Tried Raphael before and considering switching back to it as it has exactly what I'm after - http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is kind of old but you should be able to do this, you'll have to hack the map a bit. If you look at the source for the map you'll notice a bunch of path elements. Each path element has a "logicalname" *property* (not attribute). The logical name is just a bunch of data points seperated by #'s. I believe the fourth index should be the region code e.g. 002 for Africa or US for United States. If you did:

```
$("path").each(function(){ if($(this).prop("logicalname").indexOf("#{REGIONCODE}#") != -1) {/*TO STUFF HERE*/} });
```

You should be able to target specific regions. Please note that the region codes supplied to the map are dependent on the map resolution.